# In KDE when I create a file in the Home directory it also creates files on the Desktop

Tags: files, kde, directory, dolphin, duplicate

Whenever I create An new file in my Home 
directory In Dolphin it also create the same file on my desktop and on my widget (folder viewer.)

How can I fix this? It worked fine until now, but It just started doing this recently and I don't recall doing any changes to the system.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover the pointer over the Folder View's borders a little panel should be displayed. Click on the wrench icon to open the Folder View Settings. In the settings you just need to change the folder to be displayed (your home folder by default) by one of your preference (e.g., the Desktop folder).

Comment: Nope still does not work I changed and whenever I make an new folder in my home file it appears on the folder view and on my desktop.

Comment: By desktop, you mean the "Folder" view plasma widget, right?